# How to pass a file which may have a different name using Execute Shell command in Jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins, ant

I have a Jenkins job in which I want to read a file from a directory using the shell and pass that file in `ant test` step.

Say the file I want to read is `/home/xxx/y.txt`. The name of the file always changes but there will be only single file with `.txt` extension at any given point in that directory.

So, I am trying to pass that file in the "Execute Shell" build action as `ant -Dfile=/home/xxx/*.txt` but the build is "unable to read the file".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell won't expand `-Dfile=/home/xxx/*.txt` into `-Dfile=/home/xxx/y.txt` because `-Dfile=/home/xxx/y.txt` is not a file. However, the shell *will* expand `/home/xxx/*.txt` into `/home/xxx/y.txt`. You can get the result you want using command substitution:

```
ant -Dfile=`echo /home/xxx/*.txt`
```

To protect against whitespace in the file path, you can use double quotes around the backticks:

```
ant -Dfile="`echo /home/xxx/*.txt`"
```

---

*General tip*: If you are having trouble with a shell script running in a Jenkins job, try enabling command tracing and view the console output to help debug. Command tracing can be enabled in one of two ways (take your pick):

- Pass `-x` as an option to the shebang at the beginning of the script. For example, replace `#!/bin/sh` with `#!/bin/sh -x`. All commands will be output on standard error before they are executed.
- Place `set -x` somewhere in your script. Commands after this line will be traced.

Comment: The performance impact of a subshell is rather unfortunate, rather than performing the glob directly in your own shell.

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```sh
set -- /home/xxx/*.txt
{ [ "$#" -eq 1 ] && [ -e "$1" ]; } || {
  echo "ERROR: There should be exactly one file matching /home/xxx/*.txt" >&2
  exit 1
}
ant -Dfile="$1"
```

This has several advantages:

- You're actually detecting the unexpected cases instead of letting it passed unnoticed when (not *if*) an impossible thing happens.
- Everything is happening in a single shell -- there's no subshell performance impact.
- Your filenames aren't being mangled at all -- all the odd corner cases (ie. names with literal backslashes, which `echo` is [allowed by POSIX to mangle](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html)) are fully supported.
- It's fully compliant with any POSIX shell.

There's also a caveat:

- `set -- /home/xxx/*.txt` overrides `"$@"`, the argument vector, in the current context. If you need to refer to arguments as `"$1"`, `"$2"`, etc. in the outside script, you might put this code inside a function.

Comment: Nice answer! +1 from me. I have a few questions for you, though. First, why the quotes around `$#`? Isn't that always guaranteed to be a nonnegative integer? Second, why did you use `-e` instead of `-f`? I don't think that directories are valid arguments to `ant -Dfile=`. Last, are you implying that my answer is not POSIX-compliant? Because if so, I'm not seeing what you're seeing.

Comment: @Sam, the quotes around `$#` are 99% for StackOverflow's syntax highlighting, and 1% for the case where IFS contains numeric values. As for `-e` vs `-f`, the case I'm trying to catch is the case where the glob didn't expand at all, so type isn't particularly pertinent -- still, using `-f` wouldn't hurt. As for your answer -- nothing in it violates POSIX, or even depends on a shell that violates POSIX, but there are corner cases where it depends on behavior that POSIX doesn't define. Consider a filename with backslash literals -- `echo` is allowed to do whatever it wants to that name, ...

Comment: @Sam, ...and several XSI systems will mangle it by performing `printf '%b'`-style expansions, changing ie. a name with the literal string `\t` by substituting a literal tab. You might switch to `printf '%s\n' /home/xxx/*.txt` to avoid that, making behavior entirely well-defined (except for the number-of-filenames-other-than-1 case, which the OP is willing to discount).

Comment: @Sam, ...that said, the backslashes-in-`echo` thing is a very marginal corner case -- in general, your answer is a solid one.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations! I still don't understand how `IFS` containing a numeric value would affect the result of `[ $# -eq 1 ]` in such a way that quoting `$#` would be necessary, though. I exported `IFS=1` in bash 4.3.46 and performed the comparison, with and without quotes around `$#`, and got the same results. Oddly enough, I did see a different problem: when `$#` did not equal `1`, the value of `$?` after the comparison got set to an empty string, rather than `1` (like what happens when `IFS` is set to its default value). Shell bug? :)

Comment: @Sam, try `IFS=1; set -- one; echo $#`. Because it's an unquoted expansion, it gets split on characters in IFS, so you get no expanded results.

Comment: @Sam, ...alternately, `set -x; set -- one; IFS=1; [ $# -eq 1 ]` should likewise make it clear.

Comment: OK, I understand it now. What made it most clear to me was experimenting with the value of `IFS` while keeping everything else the same -- specifically, `IFS=1` vs. `IFS=2`. Interesting stuff!

Comment: (...so, to fill in for a future reader trying to follow what was happening here: If `IFS=1`, and `$?` contains `1`, then `echo $?` will result in just `echo` being run with no arguments, since the unquoted `$?` gets split on any `1` characters it contains, and it contains *only* a `1`; `echo "$?"`, by contrast, avoids string-splitting by virtue of being properly quoted and thus would emit `1`).

Answer (score 0):

```
file_name=(`/home/xxx/*.txt`)
ant -Dfile=${file_name}
```

Comment: This is only wrong because of the backticks. Take them out, and make it `file_name=( /home/xxx/*.txt )`, and you're fine. Oh -- and add some quotes: `ant -Dfile="${file_name}"`, or else names with spaces will parse incorrectly.

Comment: ...with the backticks, though, you're trying to run the first `.txt` file as a command, with any other `.txt` files passed to that command as arguments, and string-splitting and globbing the command's *output* to generate the `file_name` array. It's also worth documenting the need for a shebang specifying a shell with array support.